# Why does it takes a little longer to display 'Hello' after terminating a For loop before the printing syntax?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // single-line for-loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i--);

    // delays to execute this syntax
    printf("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it take around 10 seconds to print `Hello` in console after running it?

**Notice that the use of a semicolon at the end of the For loop is intentionally given.**

Comment: You can print the value of `i`In the `for` loop to see what's going on, e.g. `for(i=0;i<5;i--) printf("i=%d\n",i);` Note that it will probably take much longer with this output. To speed it up use `short i;` or `signed char i;` instead of `int i;`

Comment: Do you already know that, in your example code, the printf call is _not_ inside the for loop?

Comment: Integer overflow is *undefined behaviour* in C, here it is underflow and for some reason it is eventually `>=5` even though you have been decrementing it. Because the behaviour is undefined it might have taken *years*, if ever.

Comment: Show some [mre] in your question

Answer (score 0):

Since the decrement (i.e. `i--`) will be executed till infinity for `i < 5` never meets, as soon as the iterating integer `i` reaches the minimum value that an integer could hold (i.e. -2,147,483,648) get overflowed and it instantly quits the loop at negative 2147483648-th iteration.

If you write something like this:

```
int i;
long long j = 0; // intentionally using to hold lesser than the value
                 // and integer could hold for debugging test

for(i = 0; i < 5; i--)
    j = i;

printf("%d\n", j);
```

Then you'll get to know practically in which iteration the loop is quitting and the reason behind getting a few time to print `Hello` after that loop.

Comment: While this answer says the loop is “clearly” an undefined behavior, this is not clear to a person asking this question, and this answer does not say why. It does not mention the integer overflow that occurs at all. So it does not contain the answer to the question. Further, the semicolon at the end of the loop is intentional experimentation, not a fault.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how and why this happened..
It's because the range of int data type is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. "i" in this for loop is going from 0 to -2,147,483,648 (because of i--;) and after that when the value of "i"  becomes 2,147,483,647 (because of limitations of data type's range and data overflow), hence making the condition (i<5;) false and the loop stops. After that the next statement (printf("Hello");) prints "Hello".
The whole process of the loop iterating 2 Billion times takes 10 seconds by my compiler to process and after that it prints the next call (which is printf("Hello");)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i--);
```

### We don't know anything about your C implementation.

For more about the C language, see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and later the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf). Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

My guess would be that you use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler on a x86-64 computer. I recommend reading the documentation of your [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), for GCC it is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You could also need to read the documentation of your [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), so (on my Linux computer) of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

If indeed that is the case, I recommend enabling all warning and debug info, so compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You are likely to get some warnings.

You are *decrementing* `i`. Assume that `int` are 32 bits. Then on the first loop, `i` is 0; on the second loop, `i` becomes -1 .... Your computer probably will loop 2<sup>31</sup> times. So about two billions loops.

### Computers are fast, but not infinitely fast.

My recommendation: **learn to use a debugger, such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).**

At last, `<stdio.h>` gives *buffered* input output. So learn to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and read of course the documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i--);
```

Well I don't know how you got Hello even after 10 seconds! Take a closer look at the for loop. It actually never ends because the i value is constantly decreasing and hence it will always be less than 5. So I suppose the process was terminated.

Now don't think that just because you added a semi colon after the for loop the for loop won't run. It will run. Looping will take place, its just that there is no code to execute. The semi colon will be considered as a null statement by the compiler. And once the condition will return false the compiler will move on to the next statement.

Please check whether the code is correct or not. I highly doubt that it is ++i and not --i